# Improve off-topic close reason on meta

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons

The current off-topic close reason for Meta is

> Questions on Meta Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to the Stack Exchange family of websites and/or community in some way, within the scope defined in the [faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).

And if a question gets closed as off-topic most of the times you see comments explaining the close reason. For instance:

> Programming questions should be asked on StackOverflow. meta.stackoverflow is for questions about stackoverflow and stackexchange, which yours is not.

Why is that? I think because the off-topic close reason is not that great! And for a non-native-English-speaker as I am, it sounds a little confusing and bureaucratic.

Can we please have a close reason everybody just gets?

Comment: I think the FAQ has a bigger problem for non-native speakers: "If your question is about the site itself, please don't ask it here. [Visit our meta-discussion site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)...", or the "how to ask" box: "If your question is about this website, [ask it on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) instead." I have seen people asking programming questions here with the [stackoverflow] tag.

Comment: How does other people explaining that the question asked does not belong on Meta indicate a problem with the close reason? And in many cases we're talking about question-banned users anyway.

Comment: @Bart: Well, everytime I read the off-topic close reason I feel the need to add some explaining words to it. But maybe that is just me.

Comment: So the real problem is that you're just too damn helpful @juergend. Let's fix that then. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the old "off topic" close reason from before the closing overhaul (note the space instead of a hyphen), and not about the current "off-topic" close reason.

Answer (score 2):

There are two categories of programmer questions that are asked on Meta:

1. The user got lost, and
2. The user is question-banned on Stack Overflow, so they ask their question here.

The second category outnumbers the first by a wide margin.  There just aren't that many people that genuinely get lost.

Comment: Really? I had the feeling it is the other way around.

Comment: Questions asked by banned users are quickly closed and deleted, and the user binned.

Comment: The first category being the minority doesn't mean that we should forget about helping them.

Comment: @Antony: Well, we help them by closing their questions and telling them they're in the wrong place.  There just aren't that many of these.  These folks aren't reading the FAQ; changing the wording isn't going to have much effect, IMO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do we have analytics on that?